# How to get rid of the dots?

Tags: php, explode

[image: A picture of the problem]

I want to check multiple domains with my autocomplete function and it works! Only it detects a dot (**as you can see in front of the domain name)** what is probably hidden somewhere inside the code and because of the dot it will be a invalid domain name. I think it`s because of this part of my code:

```
$arr =  explode('.', $q);
```

and for the extra information, here is the rest of my code:

```
$a = array("com", "co", "net", "nl");
$q = (isset($_REQUEST["q"]) ? $_REQUEST["q"] : null);
$arr =  explode('.', $q);
$result = '';
@$domains = explode("\n", $_GET['domains']);
$domains = array_map('trim', $domains);

$output = array();
foreach ($a as &$value) {
    if (substr($value, 0, strlen(@$arr[1])) === @$arr[1])
    {
   $output[]= $arr[0] . "." . $value;

   foreach ($output as &$domeinnaam) {
   try
    {
        $domainCheckResults = Transip_DomainService::batchCheckAvailability($domains);
        foreach($domainCheckResults as $domainCheckResult)
        {
            switch($domainCheckResult->status)
            {
                case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_INYOURACCOUNT:
                    $result .= htmlspecialchars($domeinnaam->domainName) 
                                . ' &#10005;<br/>';
                break;
                case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_UNAVAILABLE:
                    $result .= htmlspecialchars($domeinnaam->domainName) 
                                . ' &#10005;<br/>';
                break;
                case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_FREE:
                    $result .= htmlspecialchars($domeinnaam->domainName) 
                                . ' &#10003;<br/>';
                break;
                case Transip_DomainService::AVAILABILITY_NOTFREE:
                    $result .= htmlspecialchars($domeinnaam->domainName) 
                                . '&#10068;<br/>';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SoapFault $e)
  {
        $result = 'Er vind een error plaats: ' . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage());
}
    } 


    echo $domeinnaam."<br>";
    echo $result;

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the word 'autocomplete'.  If this is sending off a request to the domain-checker API on **every** key-stroke, it might be picking up the dot and sending that off too.

I'd break this down into its simplest form to eliminate any quirks that might be caused by the autocomplete - get it working with a hard-coded domain and then build on top of that.  I'd also recommend removing the @ symbol to suppress errors, especially as you're troubleshooting code.

Comment: Yes but the only problem I got is the dot that's indeed getting picked up for some reason. The variables with a @ in front of it were all **notice** messages that didn't thwart things from happening. So I think it`s because of the explode part but I need that part to make it an sort of autocomplete function.

Comment: I suspect that's not the only problem.  You're sending $domains to the batchCheckAvailability call, so what's in the $q parameter that you're exploding?  It looks like you're working on $_REQUEST["q"], but then sending $_GET['domains'] to the API. I think you're going to need to clean up and simplify before the issue becomes obvious.

Comment: $q is like the **erre** in the picture, so like everything before the dot.

Answer (score -1):

It surely seems like it. you're splitting an array with '.' in between them. if you want to get rid of that, just explode it with an empty string 
explode('', $q);

Comment: You cannot explode on an empty string.

Comment: I need to explode it otherwise I couldn`t autocomplete the domain name after the dot.

Comment: you can't explode an empty string, but you can explode a string with an empty delimiter, no?